# How to Require React Components In Console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack-2

My React app is bundled with Webpack and I would like to import my component constructor to the console for debugging. If this is possible what is the syntax for importing modules to the console.

Answer (score 1):

Can't see why you would need that, but you could do something like this:

```
window.testing_one = (params) => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <App {...params} />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
};
```

Then you can manually call `testing_one({some: 'params'});` in console.

Better way would be do the testing in test environment where you can do the same thing easier. See something like: https://medium.com/selleo/testing-react-components-best-practices-2f77ac302d12

Comment: Thank you for your response but I needed a way to do this at run time.